# Use of kcore file in centos

Tags: linux

I have this kcore file in /proc/ folder. Can I remove it?

```
# ls -l /proc/kcore
-r-------- 1 root root 5368713216 Apr  5 09:01 /proc/kcore
```

What is it used for?
(using CentOS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I remove it?

No.

The entire `/proc` filesystem is a virtual filesystem that allows you to view (and manipulate in some cases) values in the kernel. As such, the "files" in `/proc` are not taking up any actual disk space.

In the case of `/proc/kcore`, it's an alias to your system memory, and will appear to be the same size as the amount of RAM available to the system.